# Need to save an entry in a field, when formatting is changed by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, web

I can provide the code for this, but I don't think it is required.

I have a State/Country dropdown in a contact form. When a state/country is selected, I have a phone field. When a US number is selected I have a script to format the number in like a standard US number. However if you select a non US country after you have entered it deletes the entry you typed in the phone field, as it changes the formatting.

Is there a way to possibly write a JQuery script to save the number in a variable and write the number back after you change the Country/State field?

The plugin I'm using to format the number is http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: tried saving the value before you change formatting and then adding saved value again into the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var origPhone = $('input#phone').val();

..do reset of form..

$('input#phone').val(origPhone);
```

This assumes your phone input has the following html:

```
<input id="phone" />
```

Can really be whatever you want, just as long as you select it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value on change the contry state. Then you could retrieve that value when is USA.

Something like, try to work around.

```
var phoneNumber;
$("#contrystate").change(function(e){
    if($("#phonefield").val() && $("#contrystate").val()!=codeUSA){
      phoneNumber = $("#phonefield").val();
    }
    else if($("#contrystate").val()==codeUSA){
      $("#phonefield").val(phoneNumber);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var inputval = $("input").val();
    if (!$("option:first", this).is(":selected")) {
        $("#input").mask($selected.val());
        $("#input").val(inputval).focus();
    }
});

<input id="input" type="text">
<select>
    <option> Select Format</option>
    <option value="999 999">999 999</option>
    <option value="99 99">99 99</option>
</select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4eUM/)